# How to invoke a function from both an outside and a sibling function in javascript / google app script

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, parent, siblings

Basic question but I can't figure it out :(. A solution to one makes the other one break. Here is the specific case narrowed down, any help is appreciated.

```
function onOpen() { // first entry point
    var helper = new level1Function();
    helper.level2FunctionA();
}

function onFormSubmit() { // second entry point
    var helper = new level1Function();
    helper.level2FunctionC();
}

function level1Function() {

    this.level2FunctionA = function() {
        console.log('hi');
    }

    function level2FunctionB() { 
        // how do I invoke level2FunctionA from here w/o breaking onOpen entry point?
    } 

    this.level2FunctionC = function() { 
        level2FunctionB(); 
    } 
}

onOpen();
onFormSubmit();
// looking for 2 hi's to the console, one through each flow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a reference to a variable self, assign to this at the top of the function body

```
function level1Function() {

    var self = this;

    this.level2FunctionA = function() {
        console.log('hi');
    }

    function level2FunctionB() { 
        self.level2FunctionA();
    } 

    this.level2FunctionC = function() { 
        level2FunctionB(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: no problem...how about you mark my answer as the answer then

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, instead of creating a reference to `self` as that is error-prone in many situations, you could use `Function.prototype.bind` and create a function `boundLevel2FunctionB`, which has `this` bound to the current `level1Function` instance (I see you're calling it using the `new` keyword).

**Code:**

```
[...] // level2Function body
function level2FunctionB() { 
    this.level2FunctionA();
} 
var boundLevel2FunctionB = level2FunctionB.bind(this);

this.level2FunctionC = function() {
    boundLevel2FunctionB();
}
[...]
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks Adrian, worked like a champ. I'll go back and upvote when I get the rep req'd to do so!

Comment: You're welcome, Dana, I'm glad it worked! Don't worry about the upvote, just make sure you give back if you find a question you have an answer for.  
Quick side-note: If you're working with that code in the browser, beware that it doesn't work in IE8 as it doesn't have `Function.prototype.bind`. You can use this polyfill from MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill